# Prove that $\frac{1}{\left(2a+b\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2b+c\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2c+a\right)^2}\ge\frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, substitution, uvw

For $a,b,c>0$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{\left(2a+b\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2b+c\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(2c+a\right)^2}\ge\frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}$$

---

Outside $a=b=c$ I can't exploit what from it